# Access ApplicationModule in Managed Bean (FacesContext NULL)

Tags: javascript, java, oracle, oracle-adf

I'm trying to get the Application Module in a managed bean class, so i can retrieve current ViewObject and change it's attributes.

I'm using DWR so i can pass a blob image as a parameter from JavaScript to this class, so i can save it on the ViewObject attribute.

My problem is that i can't retrieve the current AppModuleImpl because the 
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();` method is returning **null**.

The methods i'm using to retrieve AppModule:

On bean "FileUpload.java" (used by DWR)

```
// call VO
AppModuleImpl am = (AppModuleImpl)ADFUtil.resolvElDC("AppModuleDataControl");
ViewObjectImpl vo = am.getMyVO();
```

On utils Class "MyUtils.java" (General functions class)

```
public static Object resolvElDC(String data) {
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Application app = fc.getApplication();
ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
ELContext elContext = fc.getELContext();
ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext,
                           "#{data." + data + ".dataProvider}",
                           Object.class);
return valueExp.getValue(elContext);
}
```

Any help on how to access current AppModule / ViewObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Application Module reference from the bean using:

```
BindingContext bindingContext = BindingContext.getCurrent(); 
DCDataControl dc = bindingContext.findDataControl("AppModuleAMDataControl"); //Name of application module in datacontrolBinding.cpx
```

But to get the ViewObject you can use:

```
DCBindingContainer bc = (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
DCIteratorBinding iter = bc.findIteratorBinding("MyVOIterator");
ViewObject obj = iter.getViewObject();
```